# why cant i change image on button click?

Tags: swift, uiimageview, didset

I am trying to change an image on button click i am using didset to do so where when a variable changes so does the image butt it isn't working even though the variables are changing, here is my code:

the variable too change:

```
var page:Int=1 {
        didSet {
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
          let newW = page == 1 ? 0.04*Double(Float(bounds.size.width)) : 0.12*Double(Float(bounds.size.width))
            let newX=CGFloat(Float(Int(Float(Double(bounds.size.width)*0.5-newW*0.5))))
          
            currOption = UIImageView(image:UIImage(named: options[page-1].imagePath))
            currOption.frame = CGRect(x: newX, y: CGFloat(Int(Float(bounds.size.height/22))), width: CGFloat(newW), height: CGFloat(globW))
            }
            print("2nd Triggered", currOption)
         
        }
    }
```

the affected variable:

```
var currOption:UIImageView! = UIImageView(image:UIImage(named: "art.scnassets/A.png"))
```

where the asset string i:

```
var options:[AButtons]=[
       AButtons(imagePath: "art.scnassets/A.png", name: "A"),
       AButtons(imagePath: "art.scnassets/B.png", name: "B"),
       AButtons(imagePath: "art.scnassets/C.png", name: "C"),
       AButtons(imagePath: "art.scnassets/D.png", name: "D"),
       AButtons(imagePath: "art.scnassets/E.png", name: "E"),
        
    ]
```

the function that triggers page to change:

```
 @objc func optionClicked(sender: UIButton){
        page = sender.tag + 1
        print("1st Trigger",page, sender.tag)
    }
```

all the options objects have a tag
thanks all for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some point (although you don't show it in your example), `currOption` is added to the view hierarchy. By replacing the variable's value (ie `currOption = ...`), although you replace what's stored in`currOption`, you don't replace what is stored in the view hierarchy itself.

Trying replacing your `currOption = ...` line with:

```
currOption.image = UIImage(named: options[page-1].imagePath)
```

This is, of course, assuming that everything else is working.

Comment: Great! You can mark the answer as correct when you are able to

Comment: i know i am waiting